# Realm large query blocking the UI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I think this has been talked about quite a bit here and people are working towards passing items from background to main threads.

My question is simple. I have a large list in a UITableView when loading the list the UI for 1-2 seconds. What is the best workaround to prevent this at this point (Ideally without loading the whole fetched data in the memory)?

```
func bindTableView(term: String? = nil, segment: String? = nil) {
        resultsBag = DisposeBag()
        if let p = searchPredicateOrganisations(term) , segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            organisationsResults = realm.objects(Organisation.self).filter(p)
            sectionTitles = Set(organisationsResults.value(forKeyPath: "sectionKey") as! [String]).sorted()
            Observable.changesetFrom(organisationsResults)
                .subscribe(onNext: {organisationResults, changes in
                    self.processChanges(changes: changes)
                }).addDisposableTo(resultsBag)
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        if let i = individualsResults {
            cell.individual = i.filter("sectionKey == %@", sectionTitles[indexPath.section])[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It cannot be assumed that Realm queries are a bottleneck. Because Realm `Results` is lazy load their data. The reason for this is that Realm uses a zero-copy architecture which means we only load data you actually use. So Realm doesn't load whole data in the memory.
If you override `tableView(_ tableView:heightForRowAt indexPath:)` method, it affects table view performance. Could you show your code around queries and table view to investigate?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I think it is the bottleneck, please see above.

Comment: I don't understand what happens from your code. For example where `individualsResults` comes from?